# With Python Docopt, how can I have "one parameter or more required"?

Tags: python, docopt

I have something like this at this moment.

```
Usage:
    main.py start without ([--db] [--faced] [--ird]) [--save]
```

What I want is for `start without` to have at least one or more parameters of `--db`, `--faced`, and/or `--ird`.

The `--save` will be an optional parameter.

So `python3 -B main.py start without` will not work and `python3 -B main.py start without --save` will also not work.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently my best solution.

```
Usage:
    main.py start without ((--db) [--faced] [--ird]) [--save]
    main.py start without ([--db] (--faced) [--ird]) [--save]
    main.py start without ([--db] [--faced] (--ird)) [--save]
```

I found better solution from /u/ingolemo in my Reddit thread, https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5l3k2m/with_python_docopt_how_can_i_have_one_parameter/

```
main.py start without (--db|--faced|--ird)... [--save]
```